# Return common users using values from 2 temp tables?

Tags: sql, temp-tables

I need to return a list of Common Users where UserNames are checked if the have access to a few widgetIDs.

How is this best accomplished using SQL for SQL server 2008 R2?

```
UserNames in #DistinctUIDs table
admin1@co.com
admin2@co.com
admin3@co.com
ent_admin1@co.com
nonadmin1@co.com

WidgetIDs in #WidgetIDs table
765
768
769

Function:
 ufnGetWidgetsForUser ( @UserName )
```

I made sure I only put 1 column in each temp table. I just need to run a check on the UserName to see if the Function returns any of the values in the #widgetIDs table in other words a match.

So for example (for logics sake) a loop that checks to see admin1@co.com has access to all 3 widgets. because he needs to in order for me to reassign ownership of the widget to another User.

Is some sort of Cross-Join needed?

Comment: I don't quite understand - how are the widgets tied to a user?

Comment: @Siyual added more explanation. If Were to reassign ownership then one or MORE of those usernames need to be found as an OWNER ALSO on each widget or I cannot reassign.

Comment: Can you add desired results to the question?  I don't see what you actually want to get.

Answer (score 2):

Let me assume that this is the real question:  "I just need to run a check on the UserName to see if the Function returns any of the values in the #widgetIDs table in other words a match."

Also, let me assume that the function`ufnGetWidgetsForUser ( @UserName )` is a table valued function.

If so, I think you want `cross apply`, along with some other checking logic:

```
select distinct u.username
from #DistinctUIDs u cross apply
     dbo.ufnGetWidgetsForUser(u.username) as w(widgetId)
where w.widgetId in (select widgetId from #WidgetIds);
```

Note that I'm using `in` with a subquery here.  That might not be the most efficient way to implement the logic (a `join` could be better).  I'm doing it this way to separate the two pieces of the query:  applying the function to each user name and then checking the widget against your list.